# Background Worker Fetching data from database works fine but freeze when updating the gridview

Tags: vb.net

I have some problems with my code, I can fetch data from the database perfectly fine without any freezing, but after the fetching finish and I want to add the fetched data into the grid view, the program will freeze even though I already input the code inside background worker.

Here is the code for table declaration, I use DevExpress Grid Data if you wondering about it.

```
Dim Table1 As DataTable 
Dim ItemCode As String = ""
Dim ItemName As String = ""
Dim BrandName As String = ""
Dim FamilyName As String = ""
Dim SubFamilyName As String = ""

Sub loadtabel()
    Table1 = New DataTable("myTable")

    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("ItemCode", "str"))
    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("ItemName", "str"))
    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("BrandName", "str"))
    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("Quantity", "int"))
    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("UOM", "str"))
    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("FamilyName", "str"))
    Table1.Columns.Add(CreateColumn("SubFamilyName", "str"))

    dgvTabel.DataSource = Table1
 

End Sub
```

Here is my function to starting my BackgroundWorker

```
Sub LoadData(ByVal varItemCode As String, ByVal varItemName As String, ByVal varBrandName As String, ByVal varFamilyName As String, ByVal varSubFamilyName As String)
        loadtabel() 
  
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ItemCode = ""
        ItemName = ""
        BrandName = ""
        FamilyName = ""
        SubFamilyName = ""

        If varItemCode <> "" Then ItemCode = varItemCode
        If varItemName <> "" Then ItemName = varItemName
        If varBrandName <> "" Then BrandName = varBrandName
        If varFamilyName <> "" Then FamilyName = varFamilyName
        If varSubFamilyName <> "" Then SubFamilyName = varSubFamilyName

        pbLoading.Visible = True
        lblLoading.Text = "Fetching Data, Please Wait..."

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub
```

And here is my BackgroundWorker query, in here i also do the fetching data. fetching data from database itself takes up to 11 Second. About more than 20.000 Data. but since i use Background Worker it fetching smoothly without freezing.

```
Private Sub bgwSuburbs_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork


        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
            Dim reader As StreamReader
            Dim postData As String = ""

            Dim UrlPrefix = "http://" & My.Settings.SharedConnection & ":" & My.Settings.SharedURLPort
            request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(UrlPrefix & "/hotraxpos/item_list.php"), HttpWebRequest)

        postData = "itemcode=" & ItemCode &
                               "&itemname=" & ItemName &
                               "&brandname=" & BrandName &
                               "&familyname=" & FamilyName &
                               "&subfamilyname=" & SubFamilyName &
                               "&device_data=HC ALL IN ONE"

        request.Method = "POST"

            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()

           Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

            Dim rawresp As String
            rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

            Dim array As JArray = JArray.Parse(rawresp)

       'IF I EXCLUDE CODE FROM HERE, THE BACKGROUND WORKER WORK NORMALLY WITHOUT FREEZING
        Me.Invoke(Sub()

                      For Each item As JObject In array
                          Dim status As String = If(item("Status") Is Nothing, "", item("Status").ToString())
                          Dim Keterangan As String = If(item("Keterangan") Is Nothing, "", item("Keterangan").ToString())

                          Console.WriteLine("Keterangan: " & Keterangan)

                          If status = "SUCCESS" Then
                              Dim varItemCode = If(item("ItemCode") Is Nothing, 0, item("ItemCode").ToString)
                              Dim varItemName = If(item("ItemName") Is Nothing, 0, item("ItemName").ToString)
                              Dim varBrandName = If(item("BrandName") Is Nothing, 0, item("BrandName").ToString)
                              Dim varQuantity = If(item("Quantity") Is Nothing, 0, Val(item("Quantity").ToString))
                              Dim varUOM = If(item("UOM") Is Nothing, 0, item("UOM").ToString)
                              Dim varFamilyName = If(item("FamilyName") Is Nothing, 0, item("FamilyName").ToString)
                              Dim varSubFamilyName = If(item("SubFamilyName") Is Nothing, 0, item("SubFamilyName").ToString)

                              Dim Row1 As DataRow
                              Row1 = Table1.NewRow()

                              Row1.Item("ItemCode") = varItemCode
                              Row1.Item("ItemName") = varItemName
                              Row1.Item("BrandName") = varBrandName
                              Row1.Item("Quantity") = varQuantity
                              Row1.Item("UOM") = varUOM
                              Row1.Item("FamilyName") = varFamilyName
                              Row1.Item("SubFamilyName") = varSubFamilyName

                              Table1.Rows.Add(Row1)
                          End If
                      Next
                      dgvTabel.DataSource = Table1
                  End Sub)


    End Sub

Private Sub bgwSuburbs_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted 
    pbLoading.Visible = False

    lblLoading.Text = "Done"
End Sub
```

Just like i mention above, if i remove code at `Me.Invoke(Sub()` inside of Background Worker DoWork it work perfectly without freezing, but also without any data showing too...
please help, i just need to know how to fill the datagridview too without freezing with background worker. how do i do this ?

Comment: Don't use `Me.Invoke()`.  Also, don't assign the DataSource in the loadtabel() method.  Instead, assign it only in the RunWorkerCompleted() event, then Invalidate() the DataGridView so it updates itself.  Depending on how much data you have in the Table, there may be a delay.  If this is unacceptable, then load LESS data at a time and provide a mechanism for the user to page through the data.  It looks like you assigned the DataSource in multiple places.  Again, only assign it in the RunWorkerCompleted() event.

Comment: Further to the comment by @Idle_Mind, you should be populating the `DataTable` in the `DoWork` event handler, so it is done on the background thread. You then assign it to the `e.Result` property and then get it back from the `e.Result` property in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. Assigning that `DataTable` to the `DataSource` of the grid is the only action you perform on the UI thread.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if I populate the DataTable in the DoWork, how to assign it to the e.Result and get it from RunWorkerCompleted just like you said? can you please help me here

Comment: `e.Result` is just a property like any other. You set it in the `DoWork` event handler like you would set any other property and you get it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler like you would any other property. Don't try to make this complicated when it's not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm really sorry, but I always use double click at the object using visual studio ao all those private sub, handles, e result and other thing is always generate automatically and I never do it manually. so I really don't know how to do it,

Comment: You can generate event handlers using the drop-downs in the navigation bar at the top of the code window. As for getting and setting properties, that's not auto-generated. You always do that yourself. You are getting and setting properties all over the code you just posted. We're not here to teach you the basics. You may not know what property to set or what method to call and we can tell you that but we shouldn't have to teach you how to call a method or set a property. That is fundamental programming knowledge that you should have already learned. If you haven't, stop now and do so.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i just search it and get what you mean, i'm really sorry i know you just want to help there. by your advice i just change `dgvTabel.DataSource = Table1` into `e.Result = Table1` and at the `RunWorkerCompleted` i add this line `dgvTabel.DataSource = e.Result`. but the result is exactly the same as i made with my code above, when fetching run perfectly but when populating it freeze for 3 to 5 second. i actually want the gridview item to be added one by one row without need the program to freeze. please if you can help me again

Comment: If something takes time then it takes time. You can't make changes to the UI itself on any thread other than the UI thread and, while that thread is busy, it can't repaint the UI, hence the "freeze". You can't magic that away. Creating a lot of new rows in a `DataGridView` has to take some time. Any action on the UI thread will cause a "freeze", but most are too quick to notice. In order to do that with 20,000 rows you would have to add a break after each one and would then take ages for the grid populate. You just have to deal with it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm actually fine with a slow populating gridview as long as the program doesn't freeze, the point I actually doing this because when the program fetching data, it can do another work at another menu. and i also know it takes a long time to load since it has many data, i don't expect it to be 1 second instantly to load. i just want to make the program still run even while fetching the massive data. also for the "break" you said, is it `Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)` ? i also have try it but it still freeze too, i add those line before `next` at the loop